# Multiple connections to the same Wireless Network in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, netsh

my university just limited bandwidth to 512 kbps (that's 64 kB/s!) for each connection.
I was thinking to make multiple connection to the same wireless network (called "internet"), is this possible under Windows 7?

I know it's possible to connect to more than one WLAN through the "hostednetwork" concept in netsh:

netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=xxxxx
netsh wlan start hostednetwork

However this method doesn't seem to work, I don't know if it's due to the authentication method (through certificates while hostednetwork seems to support just a "passphrase") or because I'm already connected to that network with the same MAC.

Can you think to some tool able to do this?

Comment: Hostednetwork actually makes a connection for other devices to use to connect to your computer. You can't use it to connect to an existing network. You could try an external wireless adapter though.

Answer (score 0):

So are you talking about having two wireless adapters and having it basically raid the two connections to your one computer?

They make hardware that would allow you to do this, but your best bet is to have your own server that would have multiple wireless adapters. You would then be able to push these to one router for faster speeds.

http://sivel.net/2006/12/linux-multi-homing/

Answer (score 0):

For a Windows solution, you can check out http://asurasoft.awardspace.com/abtmulticonnect.html. I do not know how legitimate this software is, but is a step in the right direction it looks like.